# There could no multiplication on a three dimensional vector space defined similar to complex multiplication, but what an field extension of degree 3?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

According to
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field#A_motivating_example%3a_quaternions)
there could be no multiplication on a three dimensional vector space like the multiplication over the complex numbers. But what about field extensions of degree three, in these field extensions I have a multiplication for which there exists an inverse for every element??

Comment: I think you should read/understand more carefully what is said there: they're talking about *algebras* over $\,\Bbb C\,,\,\Bbb R\,$ , not simply vector spaces. And, ofcourse, there aren't many *finite* field extensions of the complex field, or of any other algebraically closed field...

Comment: The problem is that $\mathbb{R}$ in fact has no extensions of degree $3$.

Comment: That is true understanding *extensions* both as fields or as algebras. Not clear what the OP wanted to ask or focus on.

Answer (score 2):

What is written there is not very clear. It should express that there are no three dimensional $\Bbb R$ division algebras.

You are right, of course: if you have a field extension $K:F$ of degree three, then of course $K$ is a 3 dimensional $F$ division algebra!

The point is that with $\Bbb R$ the only possibilities are $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb H$, but that is because of the properties of $\Bbb R$.

You can easily get a three dimensional $\Bbb R$ algebra. For example, you can look t $\Bbb R^3$ with coordinatewise multiplication, or you can consider the ring of $2\times 2$ upper triangular matrices over $\Bbb R$. (Neither of these is a division ring.)

Comment: okay, what properties in detail. because $\mathbb{R}$ is ordered, or because it is archimedian?

Comment: It can't be either of those because $\mathbb Q$ satisfies both =D

Comment: It's that it is an associative [composition algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_algebra), which is related to having a norm that plays well with multiplication. I'm not familiar enough to narrow the reasons any further :(

Comment: @Stefan: the property is that $\mathbb{R}$ is real closed. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Schreier_theorem. A simple way to state this is that $\mathbb{R}$ satisfies the intermediate value property with respect to polynomials.

Comment: Stefan, you may be interested in googling "Frobenius Theorem"...